# Why does for(T t : this) work and what does it mean?

Tags: java, for-loop, generics, java-8, iteration

```
public abstract class MyAbstractSet<T> implements Iterable<T> { 
    ...
    // some code
    ...
    method addElement(T t){
        for (T t : this) {
           //why does this work????
        }
    }
}
```

I just finished a homework about sets and implementing `Iterable` and `Iterator`classes in Java. The whole purpose of the homework is to understand generics and collections, which I think I kind of grasp now.

However, while implementing this class above `MyAbstractSet<T>`, I typed `for(T t: this)` by mistake, which somehow confused me, since the compiler had no problems compiling it.

I tried figuring out what this meant but nothing clear yet. Like does adding the generic type `<T>` make a class some sort of list, which a for-each-loop iterates over?

Could someone explain to me why this works and what it does, maybe also post a link where this is explained in the Java documentation?

Comment: Because `this` is an `Iterable`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply said, it's a combination of these:

- An enhanced for loop, I bet you know it:

  ```
  List<String> listOfStrings = ...
  for (String string: listOfStrings)
  ```
- `T` stands for a generic type. `List<T>` is a good example.
- `this` refers to the instance of a class where is the method called. Since `this` implements `Iterable<T>`, it might be used in the enhanced loop.

Therefore, `for (T t : this)` is an enhanced loop of the very same instance of the class of all the elements accessed through [`forEach(Consumer<? super T> action)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-).

Answer (score 3):

The Java Language Specification, section [14.14.2. The enhanced for statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) says:

> The type of the *Expression* must be a subtype of the raw type `Iterable` or an array type ([§10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1)), or a compile-time error occurs.

Since your `this` object implements `Iterable`, the loop is valid, and will be iterating the elements of your set, by calling the `iterator()` method.

Your loop gets compiled to the following, except that `iter` is a hidden variable:

```
for (Iterator<T> iter = this.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    T t = iter.next();
    ...
}
```

See the JLS link above for full description of how it gets compiled.